# Error: Cannot find module 'body-Parser' deploy HEROKU

Tags: node.js, api, heroku

I searched everywhere and could not find the solution

**the error that comes out**
[image]

**package.json**

```
 {
  "name": "apirest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "API para consultar rucs de Paraguay por numero o nommbre",
  "main":"index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "Daniel Resoalbe resoalbe@gmail.com",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.4"
  }
}
```

I looked for a solution in Heroku, but I did not find it

Comment: Have you checked the log file which is listed near the bottom of the output?

Comment: somewhere in your code, you are using `body-Parser` (capital P) which is obviously not present in dependencies. it should be `body-parser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely a typo as harshalgangurde said and btw you don't even need to install body parser, it's included in express by default.
You can use these built in middleware functions for example:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```